# Role based authorization in claim-based system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I am building a brand new ASP.NET MVC application with ASPNET identity. I am thinking whether to use or a hybrid of role-based and claim-based together.

The reason for hybrid is: Use role to control wider level access (Define Groups, e.g. New Your User Group, Sydney User Group), and claim-based to control more sophisticated level of access ,e.g. controller, developer, tester).

So if I want control at the level of Sydney User Group and developer only, I can use both role and claims together.

Does this sound right, or should I just use purely claim based authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claims are key/value pairs. For example: Claim type "Email", claim value "brockallen@gmail.com".

Roles are just claims: Claim type "Role", value "Sydney".

Comment: so i assume I don't have to use uri format in my claim types right? I can give whatever name the LoB system required

Comment: Thanks so much for this guidance. I am upgrading to ASPNET identity 2.0 now. I really wish I can get some good document about best practice to use claim based ASP.NET MVC Application

Comment: @BrockAllen can you provide a database example of claim base authorization with groups and roles with their permissions?